# Write data to a char using Assembly

Tags: assembly

I created a program in C to generate a char* processedData.
I send to my assembly program and put it in a register:

```
mov     edx, [ebp+12]
mov     edi, edx
```

How can i write a char into it.
I know i need to
Write a char and inc edi... that in a loop.
But how can i write a char, i already have the value into another register.
But if i do mov edx, 49; char code i'll lose the pointer.
I want to do something like

```
for(p=malloc(100*sizeof(char*)); p!=NULL;p++){
    *p=//my char code
}
```

Assembly for linux (DEBIAN) x86

Comment: Well then, use AL? Just push EAX if you need to and pop it after.  You should really read up on Intel register architecture and assembly instructions.

Comment: The question is very unclear to me. What is "my char code" supposed to be?

Comment: like if i put 49 i must receive '1'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`edx` is the address of the destination of the char. That is, `edx` is a pointer to the location you want to write to. Therefore, do this:

```
mov byte ptr ds:[edx], 49
```

This might even work:

```
mov byte ptr ds:[edx], '1'
```

You say your character is already in some register. I assume it is an 8 bit register (`ah/al/bh/bl/ch/cl/dh/dl`), in which case you can just do:

```
mov [edx], ah
```

The assembler can infer the size of the data `[edx]` is pointing to in this case.

---

I'm on Windows right now so this code is for VC++. It demonstrates copying a string:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char src[] = "hello";
char dest[8];

int main( void )
{
   __asm
   {
      xor ecx, ecx

      mov eax, offset src
      mov edx, offset dest

        loop_dest:

      mov bh, byte ptr ds:[eax+ecx]
      mov [edx+ecx], bh

      inc ecx
      cmp ecx, size src
      jnz loop_dest
   }

   printf("%s\n", dest);
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

If your assembler uses AT&T syntax, you'll need to do some minor translation, but hopefully this points you in the right direction.

Comment: I did that, probably i misunderstood how to use it, i tried to copy and paste XD and mov byte[edx], 49.. no lucky with that

Comment: I'm using ebx, probably a mistake, i have 2 pointers.. source and destiny. I use asm to process the data, the first pointer is ebx the second (process) is edx. Can i do mov [edx], ebx?

Comment: if i do mov [edx], ebx the program stops and dont run XD.